# How large is the distance between centroids of two equilateral triangles

Tags: triangles

I have a problem. I have a triangle grid with a lot of equilateral triangles. Now I want to know what the distance is between two centroids. How can I do that?

Here is a sample image of the grid:[triangle grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nP7Cy.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you work out the perpendicular height of your triangles?

The distance from the base of a triangle to its centroid if $h \over 3$, where $h$ is the perpendicular height of the triangle.

The distance between two centroids is then this distance doubled.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing the grid length is 1 unit, we know the distance from the centroid to a side is $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}$ units. Thus the distance between two neighbouring centroids is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$. For centroids that are further apart, note that the centroids form a hexagonal grid; computation from here is not too difficult.

Comment: @tomi Ah, you're right, my mistake. I've fixed it.

Comment: It is easy to decompose the grid into triangles and show that the equilateral triangles which make up the hexagons have a third of the area of the original triangles. And that gives an easy computation of the distance.

Comment: All the triangles are connected to each other with 1 side.

Comment: I have added a image to the question!